# Cart recap displays "quantity" instead of number of products

Tags: php, woocommerce, storefront

With WooCommerce and a Storefront Child Theme, in the checkout page, the cart recap displays "quantity" instead of the actual number of products.

If I add `<?php echo $cart_item['quantity'] ?>` to the code, it displays the correct quantity value. Maybe it's the `filter` that is wrong?

**review-order.php (using [Yith-Multi-step-checkout plugin](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-multi-step-checkout/)):**

```
<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.8.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <th colspan="2" class="product-name">
                        <?php 
                        // print_r("on est là");  
                        // print_r($_product->get_name()); 
                        
                        echo '<span class="product-name__thumbnail" style="float: left; padding-right: 15px">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $cart_item['product_id'], array( 60, 120 ) ) . '</span>';

                        // echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped 

                        $splitted = product_name_split($_product->get_name());
                        $productname = $splitted[0];
                        $productcolor = $splitted[1];

                        $words = explode(' ',trim($productname));                       
                        echo '<span class="review-order-prod-name">'.'<span class="' . 'cat_product_name_word1' .'">'.$words[0]. '</span> '.'<span class="cat_product_name_word2">' .$words[1].'</span>' .'</span><br/>';
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
                        echo '<span class="review-order-prod-color">' . '–' . $productcolor.'</span>';
                        
                        ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </th>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        
        // if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        //         do_action('woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
        //     }
        
        // woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form();
        

        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td colspan="2"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td colspan="2"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?> 

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php /*            
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping fees', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_shipping_total() ?  WC()->cart->get_shipping_total() : esc_html__( 'Calculated at next step', 'woocommerce' ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            */ ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td colspan="2"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td colspan="2"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td colspan="2"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

### Edit

Also I just discovered that ticking/unticking the "ship to a different address" box, multiplies the 'QUANTITY' text!

[image]

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, do you have an idea on this? Thanks

Comment: This is hard to guess without being able debug... Where you able to determine through debugging where is the quantity text coming from? Echo stuff in order in your loop till you find the function that's causing the issue, go to it and echo inside it as well etc till you find where it's coming from :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that yout replace `sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity']` with `sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%u', $cart_item['quantity']`. Note `%s` → `%u`. There is no point in formatting an integer as a string.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change the bug.